# how to search an arraylist for duplicate objects (determined by one field) and merge them

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called PriceList

```
class PriceList {
    Integer priceListID;
    ...
}
```

and I have extended it in another class to accommodate some user functionality

```
class PriceListManager extends PriceList{
    boolean user;
    boolean manager;
}
```

One user can have an ArrayList of PriceListManager objects, that can contain duplicates (same PriceListID), so I would like to find these duplicates and compare they're fields to create one entry
eg.:

```
{ PriceListID = 5; user = false; manager = true; 
   PriceListID = 5; user = true; manager = false; }
```

should become

```
PriceListID = 5; user = true; manager = true;
```

What would be the best approach to that?
I already have equals methods for both classes, PriceList compares two objects by just checking their IDs while PriceListManagers does that AND checks if both boolean fields are the same.

**edit:** I need to find any objects with same ID, so I can merge their attributes and leave only one object.

Comment: What do you really want to do. Can you tell us in one phrase?

Comment: Please elaborate your Question.

Comment: added explanation to my original post

Comment: Since each object has a (non-unique) ID, you might want to consider using a MultiMap instead of a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
    Map<Integer, PriceListManager> map = new HashMap<Integer, PriceListManager>();

    for (PriceListManager manager : yourArrayList) {

        if (!map.contains(manager.getPriceListID())) {
            map.put(manager.getPriceListID(), manager);
        }

        if (manager.isUser()) {
            map.get(manager.getPriceListID()).setIsUser(true);
        }

        if (manager.isManager()) {
            map.get(manager.getPriceListID()).setIsManager(true);
        }
    }

    List<PriceListManager> newList = new ArrayList<PriceListManager>();
    newList.addAll(map.values());

    // Do stuff with newList....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to iterate through list and convert it into HashMap, where priceListID will be key and PriceListManager  as value. While iterating over the ArrayList, check if hashmap whether value for particular priceListID  exists :
1. if yes compare the same with current one
2. if not equal update as per your logic. 
3. If equal no need to update and 
4. if doesn't exists add it to hashmap

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think we're onto something :)

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented equals and hashCode on PriceListManager to use all fields, but for this particular purpose you need them to match on priceListID alone, right? Maybe you want to give this construction one more thought: what is your entity here? does priceListID alone already determine a priceListManager? In any case, if you want a local solution to this, i'd use a Map and then do something like this:

```
Map<Integer, PriceListManager> lookup = new HashMap<Integer, PriceListManager>();
for (PriceListManager item: priceListManagers) {
  PriceListManager manager = lookup.get(item.getPriceListID());
  if (manager == null) {
    manager = new PriceListManager();
    manager.setPriceListID(item.getPriceListID());
    manager.setUser(false);
    manager.setManager(false);
    lookup.put(manager.getPriceListID(), manager);
  }
  manager.setUser(manager.getUser() || item.getUser());
  manager.setManager(manager.getManager() || item.getManager());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates. Isn't it a good idea to work with a Set instead of an ArrayList? 
Uniqueness is guaranteed in a Set.

You gain performance and have to implement less code since you don't have to do the duplicate check afterwards...

Comment: This is not about uniquness at all. This is about merging items.

Comment: If not possible I would use the contains() method of List and implement the equals() and hashCode() methods of the objects you put in the List (in your case PriceListManager)

Comment: @Andremoniy ArrayList can contains `null`. Merge this!

Answer (score 0):

Go through the original list, and if you find an object that was already there, then merge those two into one:

```
Collection<? extends PriceList> convertToMergedList(Iterable<? extends PriceList> listWithDuplicated) {
    Map<Integer, PriceList> idToMergedObject = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for(PriceList price : listWithDuplicated) {
        if (idToMergedObject.get(price.piceListId) == null) {
            idToMergedObject.put(price.piceListId, price);
        } else {
            PriceList priceSoFar = idToMergedObject.get(price.piceListId);
            PriceList priceMerged = merge(priceSoFar, price);
            idToMergedObject.put(price.piceListId, priceMerged);
        }
    }

    return idToMergedObject.values();
}

PriceList merge(PriceList price1, PriceList price2) {
   // merging logic
}
```

I use `LinkedHashMap`, so that the original order of elements is preserved.